# Maven same dependency in multiple dependencies

Tags: maven

Let's say I have 3 libs, compiled using Maven: A, B and C.

And let's say I have this project:

[image]

Dependency C is included in A and B.

After compiling `My project`, dependency `C` will be present by 3 times? Or just once?

All of them use same version of `C`

Comment: what is the <scope>?
you can add as a compile, provided, etc. it will manage the inclusion (or not) of the artifact on the Artefact

Comment: Your own project will have it only once (if you have configured everything correctly)... The one which you have defined in `My project`....

Comment: @X-Pippes, I have no declared `<scope>` in `pom`

Comment: @KunLun what do you have in scope? thats my question

Comment: @X-Pippes, was miss spell. Sorry. I want to say `I have no declared scope`

Comment: It will there only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven manages transitive dependencies in a way that of each artifact, only one version will be used for the project.

If you have different versions, the version is decided by Maven dependency mediation.

Answer (score 0):

Before Java 9, you will have only one version, decided by Maven dependency mediation. Java 9+, if those dependencies are modules, each module can use the dependency they have listed.

Comment: Completely irrelevant. The dependency resolution is not related to the JDK. If you have created a java module for `My project` this will not really change a thing only if you have different versions of `Dependency C` but it would result in a compile failure...because it's not allowed having different versions of the same module on the module path. Furthermore you must be aware that a module in java drills down to a jar file in the end and this module `My project`  is a jar file...

Comment: @khmarbaise sure it's a jar file but the way it is loaded by the runtime matters.

Comment: Only if the jar file contains correctly a module-info.java or maybe it's a multi release jar something different...

Answer (score 0):

you will have only one C because you said its the same version.